# Deleted NSManagedObject properly deleted from tableview, then reappears when saved

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to drive a UITableViewController/UITableView. A button click triggers the deletion of an NSManagedObject via `[managedObjectContext deleteObject:aManagedObject]`.

The NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods fire properly and the row is deleted from the UITableView.

Here's where things get weird. When I call `[managedObjectContext save:&error]` the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` is called with the deleted NSManagedObject as the object (and isDeleted is YES on the managed object) and the change type is NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert which adds the deleted NSManagedObject back to the UITableView.

I've attempted to suppress the insert by checking the `isDeleted` flag in the delegate method but this causes the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` assertions to fail.

Am I doing something wrong or out of order? Did I miss a step somewhere?

Comment: Is this a part of a UIManagedDocument?

Comment: It is not. It's just straight up Core Data.

Comment: Could you provide some code? It's difficult to understand what os going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facing an exactly issue as yours I could realize that only a single reference to a deleted object by another object or context will keep it alive as a **fault** until the reference is removed. If the application try to access that deleted object again, it will crash. A single reference may be the reason why the deleted object is reappearing.

Into my case, releasing a UIViewController instance reference to the object which are going to be deleted before calling the asynchronously deletion operation fixed this issue.

```
// Delete a NSManagedObject.
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [[managedObject objectID] copy];
// Release all references to the object.
self.managedObject = Nil;
// Asynchronously delete the object.
[self asynchronouslyDeleteManagedObjectWithManagedObjectID:objectID];
```

Ignoring the `Release all references to the object` part would make the object reappears as `isDeleted` after being deleted into a `NSFetchedResultsController` observer instance.

Answer (score 0):

Did not you forget the code below?

If you are still confused, Apple's sample code, see. ll be much help to you.

[iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Configure the cell
    MyObject *recipe = (MyObject *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //do stuff
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
        UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have all the delegate methods implemented. It works as expected for deleting, but when the context saves it does an insert for the deleted NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work around for the time being:

```
[managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        resultsController.delegate = nil;
        [managedObjectContext save:nil];
        resultsController.delegate = self;
    }];
});
```

This deletes the object, let's the NSFetchedResultsController delegate fire to delete the row from the UITableView. Then the dispatch after comes later which disconnects the delegate, performs the save then reattaches the delegate.